# Where is the NavigationManager?

Tags: here-api

Where is NavigationManager? In old version, I can use NavigationManager to simulate an route, like from SF to LA.

```
NavigationManager navigationManager = NavigationManager.getInstance();
       navigationManager.addNewInstructionEventListener(new WeakReference<>(mNewInstruction));
       navigationManager.addGpsSignalListener(new WeakReference<>(mGpsSignalListener));
       navigationManager.addRerouteListener(new WeakReference<>(mRerouteListener));
       navigationManager.addPositionListener(new WeakReference<>(mPositionListener));
       navigationManager.addSafetySpotListener(new WeakReference<>(mSafetySpotListener));
       navigationManager.addLaneInfoListener(new WeakReference<>(mLaneInfoListener));
       navigationManager.addRealisticViewListener(new WeakReference<>(mRealisticViewListener));
       //set the map where the navigation will be performed
       navigationManager.setMap(mMap);
```

NavigationManager.Error error=navigationManager.simulate(mapRoute.getRoute(), 50);

Could you please tell me how can I implement simulation function with your latest here android sdk?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the latest documentation, these APIs have not changed: [NavigationManager API Reference](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/guidance/NavigationManager.html).

The way you include the HERE SDK library in your project has changed, however. It is now delivered as an AAR file rather than as separate jar and native library files. Are you sure you are including the HERE SDK properly and it is present in your classpath? For further info on the new steps see [this tutorial](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/dev_guide/topics/app-run-simple.html).

Comment: Hi Andrew,
Thanks for reply. I downloaded HERE sdk from https://developer.here.com, it only has jar file, and I didn't find any place I can download aar sdk.

Comment: It sounds like you may have downloaded the "Starter" edition which is still delivered as a jar file. The Starter version does not contain NavigationManager, you should download the "Premium" version to use it. You can find more info on the difference in features between Starter and Premium [here](https://developer.here.com/develop/mobile-sdks)

Comment: Hey @AndrewJC both links are expired..can you please update the answer with working links